# SemaphorefullException - thrown by logic error?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a multithreaded application, of which one of the classes uses a semaphore to control reading & writing. This seems to work fine most of the time, however I'm getting some inexplicable semaphorefull exceptions thrown, indicating that I'm trying to release when I shouldn't be. The problem is I've been over my code & can't seem to find a flaw in the logic which would cause this to happen.

I would be really grateful if someone could take a look at the sample code below & let me know where I'm going wrong as at this stage I think I'm beginning to go mad..

Please note that the "real" code doesn't just have a loop of threads but its pretty close

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(() => ThreadA());
            t.Start();
        }            
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Run the methods in the worker class
    /// </summary>
    private static void ThreadA()
    {
        Token token = null;
        WorkClass workClass = new WorkClass();
        try
        {
            workClass.BeginRead(out token, "A");                
        }
        finally
        {
            workClass.EndRead(token);
        }
    }       
}

/// <summary>
///  this class does the actual work
/// </summary>
public class WorkClass
{
    private Semaphore _pool = new Semaphore(2, 2);

    public void BeginRead(out Token token, string s)
    {
        Semaphore sem = null;
        try
        {
            // wait for the main semaphore to signal
            _pool.WaitOne();
            // set local semaphore equal to main
            sem = _pool;
            //simulate work
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        finally
        {
            //return the token with the semaphore
            token = new Token(sem, s);
        }
    }

    public void EndRead(Token token)
    {
        try
        {
            // do some more work
        }
        finally
        {
            // release the semaphore if not null
            if (null != token.signal)
            {
                token.signal.Release();
            }
        }
    }    
}


public class Token
{
   internal readonly Semaphore signal;
   internal readonly string s;

    internal Token(Semaphore _signal, string _s)
    {
        this.s = _s;
        this.signal = _signal;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see anything (data, semaphores) being shared.

Comment: It's a good idea to shorten the code but do make sure it reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Henk, sorry realise this code is v. long. The problem I'm having is that I can't get either this or the real code to fail, just some of my customers can! So I posted the full logic to see if anyone can see any logical flaw I've made

Answer (score 3):

One problem you're going to run into here is that you're creating a new semaphore for each instance of the `WorkClass`. So if you have three `WorkClass` instances, there will be three separate semaphores. I *think* you want your semaphore to be `static`, so that all instances share the one semaphore. You call it `_pool`, so I assume there's a limited number of shared resources that you want all instances to access.

I don't see how the code you presented in your question can throw a `SemaphoreFullException`. Are you certain that the code you posted is functionally equivalent to the code that you're having trouble with? If you compile and run the code that you posted, do you get that exception?

Comment: the code posted is functionally equivilant. The problem I'm having is that if I compile & run the real code I can't get it to fail either. We're just seeing it very intermittently in a few customer sites. I don't want my semaphore to be static since each instance of the worker class controls access to a different file, the semaphore is used for read handles

Comment: @Johnv2020: are you sure it is functionally equivalent? Why does each thread have a dedicated semaphore with **two** concurrent entries, if each semaphore is only entered once per thread (in BeginRead)? In what situation would your code ever block at `WaitOne()`? Are you sure your work class instances don't get reused between threads?

Comment: @Groo, sorry for the delay in getting back to you on this. Yes this is functionally equivilant. The real code is much more complicated the workclass is not created as a new instance but is created as a reference to a preexisting instance of the class via a static method in another class. I'm just trying to keep the posted code short enough to understand here

Comment: @Johnv2020, it's good to keep the example short, but there *is* a functional difference between using one semaphore per thread (which cannot theoretically block anything), and sharing a reference of the semaphore between classes. When dealing with threading problems, obviously the latter situation is the one which needs more examination, and in this regard your example doesn't correspond to your description of the class.

Comment: @Johnv2020, In other words, this means that: 1. **multiple** parts of your code use the same semaphore (that finally makes sense). 2. Semaphore allows **two** threads to enter the critical code simultaneously (`new Semaphore(2, 2)`); are you sure that you want two threads to access the same read handle at once?

Answer (score 2):

`Semaphore` is `IDisposable` through [WaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.aspx) - you need to make your `WorkerClass` `Dispose` it when it's `Dispose`-d of itself.

```
public class WorkClass : IDisposable

using (WorkClass workClass = new WorkClass())
```

Perhaps you are hitting some system limit under load due to unDisposed Semaphore instances? This may not be **THE** problem but it is **A** problem, regardless of any redesign you do to make `pool` static, or other singleton mechanism.

Comment: Thanks - didn't realise Semaphore was IDisposable

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are passing the semaphore outside of your worker class (wrapped in a `Token` instance) may indicate that you are using it somewhere else, other that `BeginRead` and `EndRead`.

If semaphore is used only inside the `WorkClass`, I would strongly recommend removing it from the `Token` completely - make it a private static field (as [Jim pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873271/semaphorefullexception-thrown-by-logic-error/5873498#5873498)) and hide it from the rest of the world.

Comment: I am certain that I'm only using each semaphore instance in the BeginRead & EndRead methods